# How can I put inline an SVG in Drupal7?

Tags: svg, drupal-7

I want to put my svg code in the html in Drupal7. But I have no idea which file should I put it in, or exactly which row.

I want to put an SVG menu icon in my superfish menu (in mobile mode). How should I know which file I should search?

This is for example my superfish file:

```
?>
<div <?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <nav id="main-menu" class="main-menu navigation block-content clearfix2" role="navigation">
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
     <?php if (isset($title) && $title): ?>
      <h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </nav>

</div><!-- /.block -->
```

This is my svg fle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="menu" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

And? What should I do?

Comment: create an object tag and set its data attribute to point to your SVG file.

Comment: @Robert Longson
Are you talking about this?

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/creating-custom-drupalajax-object-on-the-fly-and-attach-it-to-any-dom

Comment: No, (unless that's what you want/need to do). You've a div in your php file, just put an object tag in there too.

Comment: object? not svg?
and if I want that the svg would be before "menu" link, where should I put it? I am lost in this php file.

Comment: @Ayala, did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Save your svg file in your theme i.e. in `img` directory of your theme:

```
/sites/all/themes/my_theme/img/image.svg
```

or what ever you called the dir where you keep theme images.

Then just use it as a regular image:

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/my_theme/img/image.svg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thank you.
But I am curious how can I put svg inline.
So like this:
<svg>...</svg>

I found an example:

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="search-icon">
    <use xlink:href="/sites/all/themes/kompress/images/icons-sprite.svg#icon-kereses"></use>
</svg>

And I don't know where could I put it in my code.
I copied my code earlier.
I am a little lost in Drupal php files.

Comment: If we set this as image. Then I couldnt write css for the path

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, the simplest way is just to place the SVG code in the HTML.

```
?>
<div <?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="menu" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/>
    </symbol>
  </svg>

  <nav id="main-menu" class="main-menu navigation block-content clearfix2" role="navigation">
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
     <?php if (isset($title) && $title): ?>
      <h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </nav>

</div><!-- /.block -->
```

Reference https://css-tricks.com/pretty-good-svg-icon-system/

And Drupal 10, of course.